# Is it OK to use the participle like this: "Today I driven a car"?

Tags: syntax, participles

> Today I driven a car

or

> Today I drive a car.

Is the above sentence correct? I mean I used past participle as an adjective. I know past participles are used as an adjective but sometimes I get confused when to use an adjective or simple verb.
And tell me which one is correct and why.

Answer (score 3):

> Today I **drove** a car.

[Drove](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drove) is the simple past of the verb to drive.

You can see how to conjugate "drive" [here](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/drive.html).

> Today I will drive a car.
>   Today I will be driving a car.
>   Today I drove a car.
>   I have driven that car.

Comment: But I needed to know when use an adjective (past participle)in such a sentence.

Comment: "Driving" as an adjective is rarely, if ever, used to describe "a driving car".  There are other uses for an adjective of drive, such as "driving rain" or "driving force".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying "Today I drive a car." You don't have enough context to say whether it should be drove or will drive. "Today I drive a car. Tomorrow I will drive a limo. Next year I will own a fleet of limos.

Comment: It may be grammatical but "I am driving" is more natural.

Comment: You don't have enough context to say what would be more natural. It depends on what you're trying to communicate. 'I drive a car, not a truck' is not better as 'I am driving a car, not a truck' if I'm not actually driving my car at the moment. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I agree context is key but all I had was "today I drive". It is better to say "today I am driving".

Comment: Why is it better?

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence "Today I driven a car" is not correct. 
[Driven](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/driven) as an adjective means:

- Very determined to succeed, passionately motivated to achieve goals.
- A goal-oriented or strong-willed person.
- Having a compulsive or urgent quality.
- Propelled or motivated by something.

**Driven** can be used in sentences such as these:

> They are driven, successful people.
>
> She is very driven to find the perpetrators.

It can also be used as a suffix "-driven":

- powered by: steam-driven.
- controlled by: mouse-driven, management-driven.
- motivated, impelled, or kept in force by: market-driven, guilt-driven.

> He arrived every morning by chauffeur-driven car.